# ¿Cómo obtener la longitud y la latitud a partir de los sunrise time?

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente código que me da los sunrise times (tiempos del amanecer) ingresando la longitud y la latitud.

```
import datetime
import suntime
from suntime import Sun
from suntime import SunTimeException

lat_1 = 20.4
lon_1 = 158.2

lat_2 = 62.1
lon_2 = 58.4


sun_1 = Sun(lat_1, lon_1)
sun_2 = Sun(lat_2, lon_2)

today_sr_1 = sun_1.get_sunrise_time()
today_sr_2 = sun_2.get_sunrise_time()

print('{0} ,{1} '.format(today_sr_1.strftime('%H:%M'), today_sr_2.strftime('%H:%M')))
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para lo contrario? o sea, que ingresando los tiempos del amanecer, me de los valores de latitud y longitud

Comment: Mirando la documentación de `suntime` no se ve ningún método que devuelva eso. Puedes construir una función que vaya probando con distintas lat/long hasta encontrar una cuya salida de Sol coincida con la hora dada. Además, para una hora dada, la salida del Sol debe tocar un área, no un punto en particular.

Comment: El problema de determina la longitud a partir de la hora se conoce como "navegación celestial". Este proceso parte con una estimación de donde estás y luego, mediante tablas de almanaque, la observación de estrellas y la hora, te da la longitud. O sea, es complicado. En https://github.com/ms8r/celnav puedes encontrar un programa que lo hace. Respecto a la latitud, diria que hay dos puntos/zonas en cada hemisferio en los que el Sol sale a la misma hora (en algún momento del año, al menos).